# What percentage of a satellite's total budget goes into its launch?

Tags: artificial-satellite, mission-design, cost, cost-to-orbit

Been trying to do some personal market analysis of the space market, and realized that there doesn't seem to be any kind of statistic or average regarding how much percentage the launch of a satellite represents of the total cost to develop, deploy and manage it.

I understand that this would vary based on orbit type (LEO, MEO, GEO), orbital properties (eccentricity, inclination), satellite mass and satellite payload. However, does anyone have any kind of cost comparison or ballpark so that a percentage could possibly be calculated?

Comment: 50% to 10%?....

Comment: This varies a great deal, an average would most likely be meaningless.

Comment: Compare "standard" launch costs prior to the deployment of Falcon-9 !

Comment: You'll have a hard time finding references, as launching companies provide custom quotes for big satellites, and for small ones, prices vary wildly. But if you are okay with a  "trust me bro" answer, I'd say within satellite+launch, 10% is launch for a big satellite, and up to 60% can be launch for a cubesat. Development costs may vary wildly, with a very good estimate being known for telecom satellites (using traditional bus and payload concepts), and be close to undetermined for scientific research or new bus in new company.

Answer (score 2):

It will probably be hard to find several reputable sources of hard data that can help to answer this question, but I can provide a couple of potentially useful data points.

First, earlier this year (2023), at the IEEE Aerospace Conference in Big Sky, MA, I posed a very similar question to the speakers on a panel.

One of the speakers was Robyn Gatens (Director of the International Space Station at NASA) and she said that half of the ISS budget goes to launch costs.

The ISS data is likely to be the most heavily weighted data point in any set of data since it is currently (in 2023) the largest satellite in LEO orbit. NASA sends lots of expensive space-qualified equipment to it and NASA is probably able to leverage some economies of scale since ISS resupply runs are routine and they work with several commercial launch service providers.

Another significant data point is the Hubble Space Telescope. The Hubble mission has cost approximately \$16 billion (adjusted for inflation to 2021 dollars) since its official start in 1977. This does not include the cost of Space Shuttle operations for Hubble’s deployment and servicing missions ([ref](https://science.nasa.gov/mission/hubble/overview/faqs/)). There was one Space Shuttle mission to launch the telescope and five missions have repaired, upgraded, and replaced systems on the telescope, including all five of the main instruments ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_Space_Telescope#:%7E:text=Five%20Space%20Shuttle%20missions%20have,five%20of%20the%20main%20instruments.)). If we assume that each mission cost \$450M on average ([ref](https://web.archive.org/web/20221205113150/https://www.nasa.gov/centers/kennedy/about/information/shuttle_faq.html#10)), then the 6 missions together would have cost \$2.7B. However, other sources place the average cost of a Space Shuttle mission as high as $1.6B, in which case the cost for 6 missions would be \$9.6B. So, for the Hubble Space Telescope, launch costs have been between 14% and 36% of the total.

There is additional public data on government-sponsored research programs (for example, see figure below) but data on commercial programs is harder to  find online.
[image]

There are many different kinds of satellites and therefore a wide range of prices for satellite hardware. There are also a variety of different orbits that satellites will operate in. Some of those orbits may be accessible through the more affordable rideshare programs, and others will require a bespoke launch, which will be more expensive. For these reasons, the percentage split will vary considerably in practice.

Comment: While it's an interesting piece of information, I'm not sure why you would suggest that they use this as a rule-of-thumb. As you said it's only one data point and ISS isn't your typical satellite. ISS was only somewhat "satellite like" when its modules were being launched. Now virtually all of the launches are for resupply and crew transfer, and most of the costs are the on-orbit management of ISS. Robyn Gatens' comment would be a good answer to "What percentage of a space station's total maintenance budget goes into launches?"

Comment: The question didn't specify "a *typical* satellite" and they did say they are looking for a "ballpark" on "how much percentage the launch of a satellite represents of the total cost to develop, deploy and manage it." The question has been unanswered for three years, so I thought I'd take a crack at it. The ISS data is from a reputable source, is recent, and is an aggregate value covering multiple missions and lots of experiments. If anyone had better or additional data, I'd certainly encourage them to submit an answer. But, I will reword the rule-of-thumb statement.

Comment: BTW, Feel free to post the question "What percentage of a space station's total operating budget goes into launch?" !

Comment: The edit does improve the answer. I don't disagree that the information in your answer adds some input, especially in a vacuum (no pun intended) of any authoritative quotes or published information so far. My point was that even data from just one satellite would not create much of a measure without knowing how representative it is, and in the case of ISS I think not very representative of the OP's intent. The rewording fixes that. As for the OP not specifying what type of satellite, I think there is enough information to conclude that the OP is likely referring to single launch satellites.

Comment: I added a second data point to improve the answer. I agree that an additional answer with data on commercial satellites would be useful. Anecdotally, I have heard that both the cost and the mass of the satellite hardware are trending down.

Comment: In your latest edit you added another less representative satellite the Hubble Space Telescope, which required multiple launches as part of its ongoing operation. And "_(ISS and Hubble) should provide a rough indication of what percentage of a satellite's budget goes into its launch"_ moves the answer backwards again. As mentioned by @Mefitico size and development complexity makes launch vs. other costs wide ranging. As do operational costs, since a communications satellite will likely have less operational costs than for example a scientific instrument, and certainly less than Hubble or ISS.

Comment: Agree - this answer is biased by what data is readily available. Deleted last sentence.

Comment: "There are lots of different satellites, lots of different orbits, and **all kinds of reasons why the percentage split will vary in practice**. So I would recommend gathering more datapoints before inferring any kind of a rule-of-thumb." I'm not the resident Stickler--that's uhoh--but I think this would be more like an answer and less like a long comment if you could elaborate on the reasons you mention.  If you can't, it's just a couple of data points that may actually be misleading outliers.