# How much of NASA's annual budget goes to launch

Tags: launch, nasa, cost

I've been trying to figure out how much of NASA's budget goes to launch costs.  I would also be interested in the same question for the global space market.

**What I've tried**

I started with a simple google search, "nasa budget 2021", because I know that NASA is a government agency and so their budget is public information.  I found [exactly what I expected](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/fy_2021_budget_book_508.pdf), but it turns out NASA doesn't break down their budget the way I was hoping -- there isn't a line item for "annual launch costs".  They did have a section on the Space Launch System, a section on "Launch System Development", and a section on launch services.  I considered just adding those three numbers up, but the numbers don't seem right.  It doesn't pass the smell test.

So I went back to google.  I tried "how much of nasas budget is launch", "how much does NASA spend on launch", and then for good measure, I tried "how much does NASA spend on launch site:stackexchange.com"

At this point, I was already thinking of just posting here, but I decided to search "annual launch cost" on space.stackexchange; I didn't find any questions that were similar enough to mine.  As I typed up my question, StackExchange helpfully suggested [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41286/what-percentage-of-a-satellites-total-budget-goes-into-its-launch) as similar, but ultimately, I'm looking for a number of dollars, not a percent.

**Finding a solution**

If you happen to have a source with the exact answer I'm seeking, that would be really lucky and helpful for me.  If you don't, but you can give me a hint of where I haven't looked but could, or a simple way to calculate the answer, that's good as well (teach a man to fish, and whatnot).

Ultimately, if it comes down to it, I could probably pull information about every mission that launched in a given year, what launch vehicle(s) was(/were) used, and the total launch mass, and get a pretty good estimate by multiplying the launch vehicle's cost to orbit by the launch mass.  Pulling that information from a pdf sounds pretty time-consuming, so again, if anyone has a tip to make the process easier, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks for reading, whether or not you can help!

Comment: You're right that it's complicated.  Wayne Hale had a really good writeup on why the accounting is so tricky: https://waynehale.wordpress.com/2019/11/09/what-figure-did-you-have-in-mind/